# Trying to modify legend text in ggplot2 but end up with two legends

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to modify the text of my legend. I want to add an asterisk or a superscript to one of the keys(I know a superscript is more complicated). Here is an example of my code:

```
Shares <- ggplot(data=Share, aes_string(x="x", y= "y")) + geom_line(alpha=1,aes(group = Group, color = Group, size = Group)) +
    scale_size_manual(values = c(1,1,1,1,1)) +
    scale_x_date(name="", date_breaks=("1 year")) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="Title", limits=c(0,0.7),breaks = c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7), labels= percent (c(0, 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7)), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c(rep("solid", 100))) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=LegendColor, breaks=c("a", "b", "c",  "d", "e"), labels=c("a*", "b", "c",  "d", "e")) +  
    ggtitle(expression(Title^{1})) +
    theme_classic() + 
    guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)) + 
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,-4),"mm"), plot.title=element_text(size=27, margin=margin(t=-30, b=30)), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.line.x=element_line(color="black", size=0.5), axis.title.x=element_text(hjust=1),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0, size=20), axis.text.y=element_text(size=15), axis.line.y=element_line(color="black", size=0.5),
        legend.text=element_text(size=15), legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank()) +
    guides(size=guide_legend(nrow=2, override.aes=list(size=2)))
```

The area to focus on is the labels scale_color_manual. All I am trying to do is add an asterisk or superscript "2" to the "a" in legend text(I have an asterisk in the example). However, when I run this code, I get what I have for the labels list above what I have in the breaks list, so two legends on top of each other. Also, the guides parameters I have set for the guide legend apply to the breaks legend, not the labels one.

I have looked at other Stack articles and none of the solutions have worked. I have tried eliminating the labels parameter and overrwriting the text of the breaks legend(scale_color_hue), as well as guides(fill=FALSE) to get rid of the second legend, however nothing I have tried seems to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your code contains quite a few lines that are redundant or irrelevant, and we don't have the data to reproduce this. Could you try to make a minimal reproducible example? My guess is that you need to have the same breaks and labels etc. for the size and color scales, otherwise they get separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal plot:

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(len, dose, colour=supp, size=supp)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Changing one legend with custom labels:

```
last_plot() + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"), breaks = c("OJ", "VC"), labels = expression(alpha, beta))
```

[image]

Changing the second legend with exactly the same labels, breaks, title:

```
last_plot() + scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 2), breaks = c("OJ", "VC"), labels = expression(alpha, beta))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you baptiste! I needed to use both scale_colour_manual and scale_size_manual simultaneously, but also specify the breaks and labels in both, or else it defaults to the data names.